# Calculate the most recent two payments per customer annually then take an average

Tags: python, pandas

```
ID       2016   2017   2018    2019       
25471    $50     $0     $10    $400
22547    $0      $50    $25    $0
38754    $0     $1000   $0     $50
14523    $100   $500    $300   $0
14789    $400   $400    $400   $400
```

I would like to know how to find the two most recent payments for a customer, then subtract one from another and divide. For example for ID 22547, 2017 and 2018 are the two most recent payments. I'd like take (2018-2017/2018). I'm still very new at python and learning on my own. Any help would be appreciated. I tried to do an average between columns but that does not give me the right output.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So, what does tell you?  It results in `0.975, -1.0, -19.0, -0.666, 0`.  What possible meaning is there in those numbers?

Comment: It tells me the growth rate

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `$` and convert to integer values:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace(r"\$", "")).astype(int)
print(df)

      ID  2016  2017  2018  2019
0  25471    50     0    10   400
1  22547     0    50    25     0
2  38754     0  1000     0    50
3  14523   100   500   300     0
4  14789   400   400   400   400
```

Then:

```
df["out"] = df.loc[:, "2016":].apply(
    lambda x: (v := x[x > 0][-2:]).diff()[-1] / v[-1], axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      ID  2016  2017  2018  2019        out
0  25471    50     0    10   400   0.975000
1  22547     0    50    25     0  -1.000000
2  38754     0  1000     0    50 -19.000000
3  14523   100   500   300     0  -0.666667
4  14789   400   400   400   400   0.000000
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error. Should I be putting this in a function?
                    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax for  v :=